# When I chain/nest a middleware, I get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to run a middleware inside another middleware. When I call the nested middleware, I get an error saying:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Here's my code:

```
// middleware1
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    req.user = 'current user';
    next();
};

// middleware2
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    middleware1(req, res, next);
    if (req.user !== 'current user') return res.status(403).send('Access denied');
    next();
};


// API
router.get('/api', middleware2, async (req, res) => {
    return res.send(req.user);
});
```

What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct way to chain or nest a middleware into another one?

(The web app has more to it, but I only included whatever is necessary to reproduce the error)

Comment: Please explain why you chose to close this question. And this is a node.js question as well. (If you agree it's javascript, then it inherently is node.js...)

Comment: What is the `user` function passed in to `router.get('/api', user, [...])`?

Comment: @jknotek That was a type... I just edited it to `middleware2`

Comment: I can't say for sure if this is the problem, but the correct way to apply multiple middlewares is this: `router.get('/api', middleware1, middleware2, [...])`, instead of actually nesting `middleware1` inside `middleware2`.

Comment: I also believe jknotek has already answered you.

Comment: @jknotek So there isn't a way to call `middleware1` from `middleware2`? `middleware1` will always be a dependency in `middleware2`

Comment: @Jessica Not that I know of... One problem with nesting middleware like that is that you may end up with `next()` getting called multiple times. For example, `middleware2` calls `middleware1`, which calls `next()`, then control returns to `middleware2` eventually, which also calls next. You really don't need to nest the middleware-- they were designed to be chained instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on @jknotek comments:

Since you are passing the `next` function from middleware2 to middleware1, you are risking that the final middleware gets called in the part of the call stack, which triggers res.send. Afterwards it proceeds in middleware2, which tries to do a res.status, which will fail.

Either you want to chain middlewares as:

```
router.get('/api', middleware1, middleware2, [...])
```

Or you would want your middleware2 to behave somewhat like:

```
//middleware2
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    middleware1(req, res, () =>
        if (req.user !== 'current user') return res.status(403).send('Access denied');
        next();
    );
};
```